# getting value of my td cells by id in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have the following HTML I can see when inspecting element on google chrome.

```
<table id="table_id">
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td id="aptDate0" class="sorting_1">2015-03-08</td>
        <td id="aptDateEnd0" style="display:none;">2015-03-08</td>
        <td id="Start0">10:30:00</td>
        <td id="End0">11:30:00</td>
        <td id="Duration0">01:00:00</td>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>Jane Doe<td>
        <td id="Status0">n/a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td id="aptDate1" class="sorting_1">2015-03-08</td>
        <td id="aptDateEnd1" style="display:none;">2015-03-08</td>
        <td id="Start1">10:30:00</td>
        <td id="End1">11:30:00</td>
        <td id="Duration1">01:00:00</td>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>Jane Doe<td>
        <td id="Status1">n/a</td>
    </tr> ... and so on
</table>
```

I previously was using document.getElementById('id').innerHTML but now I have to call the function inside my $(document).ready(function() so I need to use jQuery to get the values.

I have the following loop:

```
for (i=0; i < 10; i++){

    var aptDate = $('#table_id #aptDate'+i).textContent;
    //textContent returns undefined
    var aptDate = $('#table_id #aptDate'+i).text();
    //.text() returns an empty string
    var aptDate = $('#table_id #aptDate'+i).val();
    //.val() returns undefined
    var aptDate = $('#table_id #aptDate'+i).html;
    //.html retturns function (e){return x.access(this,function(e){var       n=this[0]||{},r=0,i=this.length;if(e===t)return 1===n.nodeType?n.innerHTML.replace(gt,""):t;if(!("string"!=typeof e||Tt.test(e)||!x.support.htmlSerialize&&mt.test(e)||!x.support.leadingWhitespace&&yt.test(e)||At[(bt.exec(e)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()])){e=e.replace(vt,"<$1></$2>");try{for(;i>r;r++)n=this[r]||{},1===n.nodeType&&(x.cleanData(Ft(n,!1)),n.innerHTML=e);n=0}catch(o){}}n&&this.empty().append(e)},null,e,arguments.length)}
    console.log(aptDate);
 }
```

My datatable initialisation is as follows:

```
 $('#table_id').dataTable({
                bProcessing: true,
                bServerSide: true,
                "sAjaxSource": "script.php",
                "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {

                    if ( data[9] == "0" ) {
                        $('td:eq(9)', row).html('Not scanned');
                        $('td:eq(9)', row).css("color", "red");
                    }
                    else if (data[9] !== data[12]){
                        $('td:eq(9)', row).html('Incorrect QR Scanned');
                        $('td:eq(9)', row).css("color", "red");
                    }
                    else{
                        $('td:eq(9)', row).html('Scanned');
                    }
                    $('td:eq(1)', row).css("display", "none");
                    $('td:eq(12)', row).css("display", "none");
                    $('td:eq(13)', row).css("display", "none");

                    $('td:eq(0)', row).attr("id", "aptDate"+index);
                    $('td:eq(1)', row).attr("id", "aptDateEnd"+index);
                    $('td:eq(2)', row).attr("id", "Start"+index);
                    $('td:eq(3)', row).attr("id", "End"+index);
                    $('td:eq(4)', row).attr("id", "Duration"+index);
                    $('td:eq(7)', row).attr("id", "Status"+index);
                    $('td:eq(8)', row).attr("id", "hasInternet"+index);
                    $('td:eq(9)', row).attr("id", "QRScanned"+index);
                    $('td:eq(12)', row).attr("id", "suID");
                    $('td:eq(13)', row).attr("display", "aptID");
                    //update();
                  }
});
```

How can I get the innerHTML of my td cells. I can see they all have values on the table on screen.

**EDIT** I neglected to mention that I'm using datatables. Has this anything to do with why these solutions are not working for me?

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery you can still use `document.getElementById`, but try `.html()` although `.text()` should work - check the selector (log `$('#table_id #aptDate'+i)` and check it's returning what you expect it to)

Comment: `$('#table_id tbody tr').find( 'td#aptDate'+i).text()`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP when I tried document.getElementById I was receiving null so I assumed I had to use jQuery.. Tried to html(), it's returning undefined. The selector seems to be OK in the log, it outputted  "#table_id #aptDate0"

Comment: @JqueryKing your suggestion is returning an empty string

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I am using jQuery datatables. Is that why these suggestions are not working?

Comment: @user2363025 It depends on when you're getting the value as well, because you might be trying this before the element is created. Try getting the value at the end of your `rowCallback` function

Comment: @SmokeyPHP $('#table_id #aptDate'+i) returns: [prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "#table_id #aptDate0", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]context: documentlength: 0prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1]selector: "#table_id #aptDate0"__proto__: x[0]

Comment: @user2363025 length was 0, so no elements were found. This means they elements are probably being created after you're running that code. Have you tried it at the end of the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the initComplete and drawCallback parameters in my datatable initialisation, neither worked.

I then finally got it working using:

```
$('#table_id').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    update();
    //update fn contains my loop
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use .text() or .html(), .val() is intended to get value="" attributes. You can also use native javascript property 'textContent'.

http://jsfiddle.net/8f0oac6o/2/

```
for (i=0; i < 2; i++){
    var aptDate = $('#table_id #aptDate'+i).text();
    console.log(aptDate);
    var aptDate = $('#table_id #aptDate'+i).html();
    console.log(aptDate);
     var aptDate = document.getElementById ( "aptDate"+i ).textContent;
     console.log(aptDate);
 }
```

Comment: I have tried all 3 options, they are not working, two of which were in the question

Comment: did you check the 'http://jsfiddle.net/8f0oac6o/2/' . its logging the innerHtml date values in console. correct me if I misunderstood the question. your question had few typo errors. html() missing '()' and textcontent will not work with jquery. it is javascript native. text() internally returns innerHtml || textContent. val() is intended to be called upon input elements with value attributes and not html tag elements.

Comment: I've tried the three options with both document.getElementById and also using the jquery selector all with and without brackets

Comment: if its working in fiddle and not in your code. you should probably place a debugger and check whether '$('#table_id #aptDate'+i)' is returning html object or undefined. also check your console for other errors.

Comment: I have no other errors in the console except for the ones explained above when using different methods. I have logged out $('#table_id #aptDate'+i) and it is returning the html object

Comment: your datatable initialization '$('#table_id').dataTable()' is happening in domready as well. (i.e.,)   before calling text() or html()?

Comment: it is in the dom ready and it is initialised before calling text() or html()

Answer (score 0):

```
var aptDate = $('#table_id #aptDate'+i).html()
```

will work. but not a good solution.
you can get the value like this:

```
$('#aptDate'+i).html()
```

or

```
$('#aptDate'+i).text()
```

Comment: as stated in the question i tried .text() already. .html() returns undefined also.

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle from your example that gets the values from your  with an id attribute.
http://jsfiddle.net/jydq09L5/2/

but basically I used native Javascript since it looks like the best solution. if you don't have to use jQuery then this is the better way to go, even if it's inside the jQuery document ready function.

```
var val = document.getElementById("Start0").innerHTML;
alert(val);
```

Comment: This was my starting point, however, it's returning Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: could you recreate that happening in a fiddler?

Comment: I would guess not since you have a working demo. I've added to the question that I'm using datatables. Is this anything to do with my problems? I will add the DT initialisation to my question

Comment: My first thought is that it maybe the id isn't what you think it is after it creates the HTML structure for the table. Could you make a working fiddle with that in it? This is definitely different than what I thought it would be =)

Comment: I can't really as I can't provide the link for the ajaxsource. However, I can see when inspecting the element in chrome the generated html and the ids are indeed what we think they should be!! I'm stumped! :(

Comment: hmm if I were you I would put a debugger statement after the .dataTable() method and in the watchExpressions in chrome or in the console look on the properties.

Comment: what sort of debugger statement? Do you mean a console.log()? Excuse my ignorance, I know nothing about watchExpressions in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td id="aptDate0" name="data" class="sorting_1">2015-03-08</td>
        <td id="aptDateEnd0" name="data" style="display:none;">2015-03-08</td>
        <td id="Start0" name="data">10:30:00</td>
        <td id="End0" name="data">11:30:00</td>
        <td id="Duration0" name="data">01:00:00</td>
        <td name ="data" id="name1">John Doe</td>
        <td name="data" id="name1">Jane Doe</td>
        <td name="data" id="Status0">n/a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td id="aptDate1" name="data" class="sorting_1">2015-03-08</td>
        <td id="aptDateEnd1" name="data" style="display:none;">2015-03-08</td>
        <td id="Start1" name="data">10:30:00</td>
        <td id="End1" name="data">11:30:00</td>
        <td id="Duration1" name="data">01:00:00</td>
        <td name="data" id="name2">John Doe</td>
        <td name="data" id="name2">
            Jane Doe
        </td>
        <td id="Status1" name="data">n/a</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script>

    $('td[name=data]').click(function () {
        alert($(this.id).html());
    });

</script>
```

try above code, its working for me, i just have added id in name cell and gave same to all cells, so i can get html of cell by single function in jquery...

Try It.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop runs from 0 to 9. Are you sure that you have enough rows? When the td is present, .html() returns the correct value. When the td does not exist however, .html returns the mentioned function and .html() returns undefined.

Comment: there are 10 rows present. I am getting the undefined in the first iteration of the loop anyhow :/

Comment: Could this maybe be a timing-issue? It looks like the rows are added in a callback. Maybe you're trying to read the content before it's there. That may the reason you're getting the error in the first iteration and this may also be the reason that you do see the rows when inspecting in Chrome.

Comment: maybe? How would I solve this? I have initialised before I call the function with the loop?

Comment: You could try running the for-loop at the end of the callback function. If it then works, then you're sure it's a timing issue.

Comment: I put it in the fnrowcallback and its printing ten empty strings??

Comment: From [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) rowCallback allows you to 'post process' each row after it have been generated for each table draw, but before it is rendered into the document. I think you need "initComplete"

Comment: I've added the initComplete parameter to my datatable initialisation and that gives 10 empty strings also

Comment: thanks for all the help, i had just stumbled acrossed that myself and got it working :)